# Fetch data from office 365/ SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a question for the community. Here's a bit of background before I ask my question. I'm in charge of redoing our employee intranet.

We currently use office365/SharePoint 2013. I'm doing a full effort SharePoint branding. Our intranet is going to be converted from plain HTML into a SharePoint master page. The question I have for the community that I was not able to find through searching is is there a way to fetch multiple files stored on SharePoint and display them as a list.

Thank you in advance.